# Scale Regression Summary in Beamer Presentation

Tags: r, markdown, summary, beamer

In order to create a presentation, I use R Markdown. I'd like to print a linear regression (lm) or mixed-effects model (lmer) summary on a slide. However, it does not fit neatly on the slide and I searched the web for a method that allows me to scale the summary, but I couldn't find anything useful. Of course, I could delve deeply into the LaTeX configuration of my Markdown document. However, I was wondering whether there is a quick solution e.g., using a certain package, function or set up the relevant chunk differently?

Comment: please make a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I use `stargazer` to create the regresssion tables, there you can change the font size with `font.size`, the column spacing with`column.sep.width` and/or print the regressions on one row with `single.row = TRUE`.